# how to auto transfer table data from outlook with mails having specific subject to excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I have been working on this problem to auto transfer data from outlook to excel from mails with specific subject, can anyone make it so that the code when pasting the info onto excel, it doesn't delete the old data and checks my entire mailbox including old and new mails. Here is the code that I currently have.

```
Sub GetFromInbox()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i, j, eRow As Long
Dim olMail1 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set olHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim olEleColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim t
Dim posicao As String

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Subject"

i = 1
xRow = 1
For Each olMail In olItms
    If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Memo required") > 0 Then
'    If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Supplier2 Pipeline Schedule - 26 Mar 2021") > 0 Then
        With olHTML
            .body.innerHTML = olMail.HTMLBody
            Set olEleColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        End With
        
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            'which row to start
            eRow = 1
            posicao = "A" & eRow
            For Each t In olEleColl
                For i = 0 To t.Rows.Length - 1
                    For j = 0 To t.Rows(i).Cells.Length - 1
                        'ignore any problems with merged cells etc
                        On Error Resume Next
                        .Range(posicao).Offset(i, j).Value = t.Rows(i).Cells(j).innerText
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    Next j
                Next i
                'define from which row the next table will be written
                eRow = eRow + t.Rows.Length + 1
                posicao = "A" & eRow
            Next t
        End With
    End If
Next olMail

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = " " Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i


Set olFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `eRow = 1` >> `eRow = .Cells(rows.count,"A").End(xlUp)+1`

Comment: "including old and new mails" - there's nothing in your code which filters any mails out

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. I am completely new to VBA so i just want to ask if the first comment that you have made is to make sure the old data doesn't get deleted when the new data comes in, right?

Comment: And is there any way to make it that when the data is transferred only the 2nd column of the table is taken and the first column is ignored?

Comment: Provided there’s always content in ColA it should always start at the next empty row based on that column.

Answer (score 0):

To start after the previously-copied table, and to skip the first column in each table:

```vb
       '...
       '...
       Dim cPos As Range 'start cell for copied table
       
       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
           Set cPos = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'next empty cell in ColA
       End With
       
       For Each t In olEleColl
            For i = 0 To t.Rows.Length - 1
                For j = 1 To t.Rows(i).Cells.Length - 1  'start at second cell
                   'ignore any problems with merged cells etc
                   On Error Resume Next
                   cPos.Offset(i, j-1).Value = t.Rows(i).Cells(j).innerText
                   On Error GoTo 0
                Next j
            Next i                
            eRow = eRow + t.Rows.Length + 1 'increment for next table
        Next t
        '...
        '...
```