# Formatting data which has been transferred into excel from outlook into a table

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have worked on a VBA code that transfers data from outlook to excel, but I need to add the data to a table which already has content. So the project I am working on is to automate the entry of data into an excel table from specific outlook mails. Can anyone help with the code so that the data gets formatted into the table without deleting the old data? This is how the data from Outlook enters into the excel - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twv5u.png); these are 2 different things that have to be put into the table as 2 separate entries. But the tough part is that the number of entries is different every time. Sometimes it can be 2, and sometimes, the data to be entered into the table can be 10.

This is what the table looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Tlt.png), The data has to be entered into this table. The table and the worksheet where the data comes into from excel are in the same workbook.

And just a final question is it possible to integrate into the code, that whenever the data is transferred into the table, the data from [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twv5u.png) here gets deleted so that there is space for new data to be added?

This is the code that I have to transfer the data from Outlook to excel in the specifications that I require.

```
Sub GetFromInbox()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItms As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i, j, eRow As Long
Dim olMail1 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument: Set olHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim olEleColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim t
Dim posicao As String

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = olFldr.Items

olItms.Sort "Subject"

i = 1
xRow = 1
For Each olMail In olItms
    If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Memo required") > 0 Then
'    If InStr(1, olMail.Subject, "Supplier2 Pipeline Schedule - 26 Mar 2021") > 0 Then
        With olHTML
            .body.innerHTML = olMail.HTMLBody
            Set olEleColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        End With
        
               Dim cPos As Range 'start cell for copied table
       
       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
           Set cPos = .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'next empty cell in ColA
       End With
       
       For Each t In olEleColl
            For i = 0 To t.Rows.Length - 1
                For j = 1 To t.Rows(i).Cells.Length - 1  'start at second cell
                   'ignore any problems with merged cells etc
                   On Error Resume Next
                   cPos.Offset(i, j-1).Value = t.Rows(i).Cells(j).innerText
                   On Error GoTo 0
                Next j
            Next i                
            eRow = eRow + t.Rows.Length + 1 'increment for next table
        Next t

        End With
    End If
Next olMail

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = Last To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(i, "A").Value) = " " Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i


Set olFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to change `eRow = eRow + t.Rows.Length + 1` line to `Set cPos = cPos.Offset(t.Rows.length + 1)` to get next empty row.

Comment: As an alternative to VBA, try using Power Query to connect to MS Exchange. You can build a query to format your new data table and then append to the old data table.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76489121/how-to-auto-transfer-table-data-from-outlook-with-mails-having-specific-subject